# How to install the Android ADB Interface on an HP 8 Tablet?

Tags: windows-8, usb, drivers, android

I purchased an HP 8 Tablet today running Android 4.2. When I plugged the USB cable into my Windows 8.1 laptop it recognized the device and let me browse the internal storage but the device had a warning icon in Device Manager and it said the driver was not installed properly. I tried to use ADB to copy an APK to the device and it said the device could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the Google USB driver that ships with the Android SDK but I had o follow the steps [here](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/usbdebug/manualinstall.php) to manually install the ADB interface.

In summary, you have to choose to "Browse my computer for eriver software", then choose "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer", then leave "Show All Devices" selected and click Next, then choose "Have Disk..." and browse to the Google USB driver folder in the sdk/extras/google/ folder of the Android SDK. You will need to download the Google USB driver with the SDK Manager first.

After following these steps I was able to use ADB to copy APK's to my device and I was able to debug from Eclipse.